# how to install PyQtChart in python34, pyqt5.4

Tags: qt5, pyqt5, qtcharts

I want to use [Qt Chart](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html) in my application, so I find PyQtChart5.7 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQtChart/5.7 . 
But I've tried `pip3 install PyQtChart` failed:

```
Downloading/unpacking PyQtChart
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyQtChart
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for PyQtChart
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\zhangqi2011\pip\pip.log
```

and `pip3 install PyQtChart-5.7-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl` failed too.

I try to download PyQtChart_gpl-5.7.zip (sorry i can't post more than 2 links...) , but I don't know how to add it to my python site-packages? Please help me...

my environments:
win7
python34
**pyqt5.4** (pyqtchart version is 5.7...?)

Answer (score 1):

Your Python/PyQt5 installation is too old. You need to upgrade to Python-3.5 and PyQt-5.7 to use PyQtChart-5.7.

There are no older versions currently available through the [official PyQtChart download site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQtChart/), and a web-search doesn't find any older packages elsewhere on the net. So it's PyQtChart-5.7 or nothing.